# Ajax pass data to a URL

Tags: java, ajax, model-view-controller

I wonder if someone could help me out please? What I'm trying to achieve (via ajax) is to pass parameters to a URL but not on the query string as I don't want to expose the parameters.

So I have a page which contains an Index method:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int qualID)
    {
        //do stuff with qualID and load up a model

        return PartialView("ICTEnrolmentForm", myNewModel);
    }
```

and on (a completely separate page) I have the following block of ajax:

```
<script>
    var enrolmentURL = "/enrolment/";
    $('.enrolNow').click(function (e) { 
        var qualID = $(this).attr('data-qual');
        $.ajax({
           url: enrolmentURL,
           type: 'POST',
           data: { 'qualID': qualID },
           success: function(model)
           {   
                window.location = enrolmentURL;
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

If if create a breakpoint on the ActionResult method I can see that the method is being called (with the QualID populated) but then the redirect is fired and I'm getting an Null parameter error.

I'm obviously being really dim but if someone could point out the error of my ways that'd be much appreciated.

Thanks,
C

Comment: You cannot send data in a request without exposing it. You can try encoding or encrypting, but the data itself will still be "exposed"

Comment: So I have to build URL with QS parameters?

Comment: If it's a `GET` request then the params are going to be part of the URL. If it's a `POST` request, then the data will be available to the user if they inspect network traffic (Dev tools).

Comment: Can you post the whole error message? 
You can't hide the data sent to the server from the user.

Comment: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'qualID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in 'ICASolution.Controllers.ICTEnrolmentFormSurfaceController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Answer (score 0):

if you use spring boot, add this in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/enrolment/",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ActionResult Index(@RequestParam(value = "qualID" , required = false) String qualID)
        {
            //do stuff with qualID and load up a model

            return PartialView("ICTEnrolmentForm", myNewModel);
        }
```

Comment: Urm what's string boot?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is C# code and not Java, as mentioned in the TAG section?

The problem is that qualID can be `NULL` if you invoke the controller method via HTTP. However, qualID has the datatype Int32 which can't be null. So you have to change the datatype and the method signature to

`public ActionResult Index(int? qualID)`

Now, qualID is allowed to be `NULL`(you have to check this before you use the variable in your code and throw an appropriate error message). Additionally, check your defined routes.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this an answer or not but I've found a workaround basically I do an ajax post to another method which populates the model and puts the model into a session variable then upon success I'm doing the redirect to the URL which loads the session model onto the page.

The URL stays clean which is the main thing that I was after.

Thanks for your time folks.